# request.user showing "AnonymousUser" in django classview dispatch method but not in "get_object" method

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
    

    # @method_decorator(custom_ratelimit)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        print(request.user)  # return "AnonymousUser"

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # some lines of code
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def get_object(self):
        user=self.request.user
        print(user) # return user EMAIL (I am using custom user model)
        # some code

       
        return obj
```

I am not able to understand why `dispatch()` method not able to find user on other hand `get_object()` method is able to find the user and returning user email.

FYI- I am using a custom user model and instead of a username I am using email. I want to use a decorator to count request limits for that reason I am using this dispatch method to pass users.

Comment: What does it print if you instantied the super return as the variable ret, and print the request.user afterwards? Also, it might be helpful to see code relating to your settings about DRF

Comment: I think at the point where dispatch() is called, the authentication middleware has not yet associated the user with the request, that why it is showing AnonymousUser. But I am not confirm on this.

Answer (score 0):

That should not even be possible, since you have:

```
authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

These attributes are verified before any method is called. While `JWTAuthentication` is responsible for authenticating `IsAuthenticated` makes sure that the user is present in the `request` and `is_authenticated`. Otherwise an exception is raised:

`APIView` class snippet:

```
...
def permission_denied(self, request, message=None, code=None):
    """
    If request is not permitted, determine what kind of exception to raise.
    """
    if request.authenticators and not request.successful_authenticator:
        raise exceptions.NotAuthenticated()
    raise exceptions.PermissionDenied(detail=message, code=code)
...
```

That being said, you shouldn't be trying to implement this on your own, `DRF` already provides requests limiting functionality through [**`Throttling`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/):

views.py

```py
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    ...
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    throttle_classes = [UserRateThrottle]
```

settings.py

```py
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'user': '10/day'
    }
}
```

Now, If, for instance you want to count the number of requests left, then it is a bit more tricky, because the built-in classes are made only to limit the number of request and not to give information about it. One solution would be to write a helper function to obtain such information:

```
def count_request_left(throttle_class, request, view):
    """
    Helper function to count how many requests are left
    for a given throttle class
    """
    key = throttle_class.get_cache_key(request, view)
    history = throttle_class.cache.get(key, [])
    num_requests, duration = throttle_class.parse_rate(throttle_class.get_rate())
    num_requests_left = num_requests - len(history)
    msg = f"{throttle_class.__class__.__name__} has {num_requests_left} requests left"
    return msg
```

To see this in action, you can override one of your `view` methods:

```py
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    ...

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        [
            print(count_request_left(throttle_class, request, self.list))
            for throttle_class in self.get_throttles()
        ]

        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The output for some user first request would be `UserRateThrottle has 9 requests left.`